# How to add a custom image in MGWT ImageButton

Tags: mgwt

I am new to mgwt , 
I just added ImageButton and simply trying to put my custom image in it

This is my button

```
   <b:ImageButton ui:field="imgButton_settings" > Settings   </b:ImageButton>
```

in my java class I am assigning this image resource to this button

```
      imgButton_settings.setIcon(Resources.INSTANCE.myIcon());
```

But the button image area is still black

I also tried this way

```
  ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton("logo.png");
```

But no luck

Any Suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a few classes. First, is an image holder where you add your images:

```
public class ImageHolder {
  private static final Appearance APPEARANCE = GWT.create(Appearance.class);

  public interface Appearance {
    public interface Images {
      ImageResource myIcon();
    }
    Images get();
  }

  public static Appearance.Images get() {
    return APPEARANCE.get();
  }
}
```

Then, you define 3 or 4 classes to get a different image based on a device pixel density:

```
public class ImageHolderDefaultAppearance implements ImageHolder.Appearance {
  interface Resources extends ClientBundle, Images {
    Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Override
    @Source("myIcon_mdpi.png")
    ImageResource myIcon();
  }

  @Override
  public Images get() {
    return Resources.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Similarly, you create a class ImageHolderDefaultHighAppearance with `myIcon_hdpi.png`, etc.

In your gwt.xml file for this module you need to define deferred binding rules:

```
  <replace-with class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolderDefaultAppearance">
    <when-type-is class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolder.Appearance" />
  </replace-with>
  <replace-with class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolderDefaultHighAppearance">
    <when-type-is class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolder.Appearance" />
    <when-property-is name="mgwt.density" value="high" />
  </replace-with>
  <replace-with class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolderDefaultXHighAppearance">
    <when-type-is class="com.myClient.icons.ImageHolder.Appearance" />
    <when-property-is name="mgwt.density" value="xhigh" />
  </replace-with>
```

Now you can use these icons in your app by calling `ImageHolder.get().myIcon()`

Comment: thanks ,Using this code and then setting my button as:  imgButton_Recommendations.setIcon(MyImageHolder.get().myIcon()); 

when i run this it says:Deferred binding result type 'com.mgwt.client.MyImageHolder.Appearance' should not be abstract

Comment: This is probably because you specified ImageHolderDefaultAppearance, but not ImageHolderDefaultHighAppearance and ImageHolderDefaultXHighAppearance. You have to account for all possible values of mgwt.density.

Comment: Created two copies of the class ImageHolderDefaultAppearance... Named as ImageHolderDefaultHighAppearance AND ImageHolderDefaultXHighAppearance.... with different images i @source ..Also then added in gwt.xml...but still same error.

Comment: This error means that the compiler tries to substitute `ImageHolder.Appearance` with a specific implementation, but it cannot find it. It can be something as simple as a typo in `<replace-with>` statement.

Comment: ahh yeah , u right , it was typo , error gone , But the image not coming up , i am using image button and doing imgButton_Recommendations.setIcon(MyImageHolder.get().myIcon()); is it the right way.. after that the left icon area of my button sizes increas (coz image is a bit large)  but its Black color not showing the image..

Comment: Inspect it in your browser. I can't help with that without seeing the image and how it is rendered.